# How to create a unique random string in PHP and SQL relational data base?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, unique-key

I am making a replica / clone of you tube . But I  am facing a problem of making very unique id for videos , channels , playlist etc.. as the yt do .

### Video Id

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6Hai-W9pRE

unique video id = G6Hai-W9pRE
```

### Channel ID

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeVMnSShP_Iviwkknt83cww

unique channel id = UCeVMnSShP_Iviwkknt83cww
```

I researched on internet and find some solutions like .

### solution 1

```
step - 1 : create a random number / string

step - 2 : search for the string in the database , if found return to step 1 or you found your 
           unique id
```

### Problem

finding a unique no from 1-100000000 if 90% of the numbers are used is not a great or effective way **I Think**

### solution 2

```
uuid() concept or similar to this random no generator concepts
```

But I am not sure if they are good for my requirement , or if the same thing done by 2 parallel running scripts then ?? I will end up with non unique or duplicate ids ...

## What I want  to know is ---

1. what is the most effective way of doing this ( Generating a unique random string ) .
2. What method has done by **You Tube**
3. What method should I use .

I am just knew to this platform and don't know where can I found this type of question's solution.
It would be great if you can answer my question with a great elaboration and explanation.

Thanks In advance ;

Comment: You may use sequences to get incrementing numbers. This is their purpose

Comment: so what about strings .. like `unique channel id = UCeVMnSShP_Iviwkknt83cww`

Comment: Quickest and simplest would be a GUID, the algorithm will ensure uniqueness and takes no time to generate. If you want to be fancier you could perhaps hash some unique properties about the video and its uploader and use the hash as the id.

Comment: Dazz can you explain what you are saying and what method has used by yt ? and which unique properties can I hash ? Please I want a very deep insight

Comment: What are the requirements?  You mentioned "unique".  But what about "not easily hacked" (hence not a simple number)?  How about "able to reconstruct the original string" (as with encryption)?  Other?

Answer (score 0):

You should use MySQL's built in `uuid()` function.

`uuid()` will generate unique values, even [if two are generated at the same time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). The `uuid()` has 3 components:

1. The first 3 parts are generated from the timestamp
2. The fourth part is a random string to compensate for the timestamp possibly being the same in two different calls
3. The fifth part is an IEEE 802 node number to distinguish the uuid spatially.

You shouldn't worry about duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`MD5()` and `SHA1()` are one-way encryptions that are essentially unique.  Use against whatever unique value you want to hide from the users.  The result is hex, which could be converted to base64 or binary.  There is no way for a hacker to retrieve the original string.

`BASE64()`.  Apply this to something that is unique.  But note that it is reversible.  That is, a hacker can trivially reconstruct the value it came from.  (`post.it`, etc, seem to do this.)

`RAND()`.  Too messy to use due to the growing chance of repeats.  Furthermore, it repeats after 2^30 calls.

MD5(auto_inc).  Internally use `AUTO_INCREMENT` to get 1,2,3,...  Then hide it with a one-way hash.  However, a dictionary lookup (used by password crackers) would quickly recognize `c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b` as `MD5(1)`.

I would *guess* that YouTube (etc) do something trivial like `AUTO_INCREMENT` `BASE64`.  This has the advantage of getting longer and longer as the numbers grow:

```
+------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| TO_BASE64(0x100) | TO_BASE64(0x10000) | TO_BASE64(0x1000000) |
+------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| AQA=             | AQAA               | AQAAAA==             |
+------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

(The trailing `=`s can be removed without loss of information.)

`UUID()`.  See Joundill's answer.  That is describe "type 4", which MySQL uses.  There are other types.

Size:

Hex (MD5, etc) -- 4 bits per character.
UUID -- hex, plus some dashes, hence average of slightly less than 4.
BASE64 -- almost 6 bits per character.
Binary -- not practical in URLs; it would get expanded (eg, `urlencode()`) into something worse than 4/char.